# PHP - Accessing a global variable across all php threads

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am using pthreads for my PHP application.

I want my threads to read/write (share) a common PHP variable, i.e. maintain the common variable state for all threads within a User Session.

I have found no solution. Please also give any script example with the solution proposed.

Comment: i dont use pthreads but maybe its a solution to use memcache or shared memory ;)

Comment: Please try to refrain from asking for urgency in your questions - it doesn't get answers any faster, but may get you a downvote!

Comment: The author and maintainer of Pthreads answered your question below - did it help? If so, please consider accepting it, voting on it or replying to it.

Answer (score 0):

In most web setups, this is not feasible. It's not feasible because there are several processes serving requests; processes which cannot access each others memory.

Even if it were possible, it would not be sensible; this is exactly the kind of locking that cripples the default file based session handlers in PHP: You do not want all processes to lock up over one critical section, it's bad design.