# php - can't access global variables from Thread?

Tags: php, multithreading, scope, global

I suppose this is a specific question, but for some reason, when I create a Thread like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/myotherfile.php');
class StreamBufferInput extends Thread {
    public function run(){
            global $max_buffer_size;
            global $data_source;    
            echo "DATA:" . $max_buffer_size;
            ...
    }
}
```

`myotherfile.php` has those two variables declared in it (and they can be accessed from other classes, but my `echo` statement here prints `DATA:` and nothing else. I couldn't find much on doing global variables within classes, but I have a global declaration like this in a function of one of my other classes, and it works fine.

EDIT: Here is how I'm starting the Thread.

```
$stream = new StreamBufferInput();
$stream->start();
```

Comment: Maybe the run() method is called before a value is actually set to the variable?

Comment: Where did  you read that you can access global variables from threads?

Comment: @Osuwariboy Thanks for the response, I just checked and this is not the case - there is an include of the file with the global variables prior to the thread's start.

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733844/php-accessing-a-global-variable-across-all-php-threads)

Comment: @Osuwariboy I thought things might have changed in a year. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in PHP at the moment. You cannot access global scope variables defined outside a thread from within the thread itself. However, you can execute a callable from within the thread, in the global scope by using `Thread::globally`, I believe this could help you achieve what you want.

You can read some more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.globally.php)