# How to access global variable in run function of pthread in php

Tags: php, pthreads

I have trouble to access variable globally in pthread run function, can I know how do I do it?

```
class Promise extends Thread
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        global $myVar;
         echo "inside construct function variable " . $myVar;
     }

        public function run()
    {
        global $myVar;
         echo "inside run function variable " . $myVar;
   }
}
```

I can access the myVar global variable in construct but not run function? Can I know why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - can't access global variables from Thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525517/php-cant-access-global-variables-from-thread) - may I suggest to follow the referenced link or check if there has been a change in the language rules since that question has been posed, and then maybe come back and edit the question accordingly?

Comment: @Dilettant I have tried the answer yet it still cant access the global variable

Comment: Could that then mean, that this indeed is not possible in current PHP versions - so that this would be the answer (with reason: Not implemented by language PHP) ?

Comment: I am not so sure about that too :(

Comment: Ah ok. Annoying situation. Maybe someone else knowing comes along and fills in the gaps then. Good luck!