# how to run Thead on ratchet php

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, ratchet

I am creating a web application using Ratchet php web socket and I want to use it in the circumstance where when the client send connect to the socket via `onOpen` it will retrieve some data from the database and send some data back to the client. The problem is when I have two client connect to the same web server, the `onOpen` event did not fired until the first one finished executing(retrieve data from db takes times) which means it is not asynchronous/concurrent.

I know I can create a thread using pthread but I cant pass connection object to the thread as stated in : [How to access global variable in run function of pthread in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725209/how-to-access-global-variable-in-run-function-of-pthread-in-php)

This is my code for your reference :

```
  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $ch = curl_init();


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mywebsite.com/example.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        echo "finished executing";
    }
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @Mu'menYassin hello, thanks for the replied, I updated my question

Comment: i assume that you are trying to access the `$data123` from the global scope?

Comment: @Mu'menYassin no, sorry what I mean is the curl request takes like 10 second to response if my page is really big. And the problem is when the second client connect to the socket, the onOpen event is not fired until 10 second later

Comment: What about creating a new thread inside the `onOpen` and use `Thread::globally(function(){//your curl request goes here... });` to send your request?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I cant get the connection object inside Thread::globally which I need to send message to the client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114610/discussion-between-mumen-yassin-and-dramasea).